# Google Play Game Services Real Time Multiplayer Room Error STATUS_OPERATION_IN_FLIGHT

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have an application that uses the Google Play Game services real time multiplayer to automatch players. Creating a room is normally successful and the multiplayer will work correctly, except if the internet connection drops when trying to create a room.

If the internet drops while creating a room I get back a [STATUS_REAL_TIME_CONNECTION_FAILED](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesStatusCodes.html#STATUS_REAL_TIME_CONNECTION_FAILED) error in the RoomUpdateListener onRoomCreated(...).

**My application is then stuck in the STATUS_OPERATION_IN_FLIGHT state when trying to create another room. I need to clear the application data to recover from this.**

It seems like the failed original creation of the room put it into a bad state and won't allow the creation of another room. I don't see any way to cancel the room creation other than calling [Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMultiplayer.html#leave%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomUpdateListener,%20java.lang.String%29) which requires a room id that I don't have since the room creation was never successful.

---

Here is how I am setting up my RoomConfig:

```
final Bundle autoMatchBundle = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, 0);

final RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(roomUpdateListener);
roomConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(realTimeMessageReceivedListener);
roomConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(roomStatusUpdateListener);
roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchBundle);

roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
```

Here is how I am creating a room:

```
Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(googleApiClient, roomConfig);
```

---

**Solution**: I reconnect the googleApiClient when getting in this state.

I do the following in my RoomUpdateListener onRoomConnected implementation:

```
@Override
public void onRoomCreated(final int statusCode, final Room room) {
  if (statusCode != GamesClient.STATUS_OK) {
    if (statusCode == GamesClient.STATUS_OPERATION_IN_FLIGHT) {
      googleApiClient.reconnect();
    }

    // OMITTED ERROR CASE CODE

    return;
  }

  // OMITTED SUCCESS CASE CODE

}
```

---

*I am still not sure why it gets stuck in this state in the first place.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `onRoomCreated` called?

Comment: Also, the documentation says that **The lifetime of the current game's connection to the room is bound to this GoogleApiClient's lifecycle.** So maybe you have to restart your `GoogleApiClient`.

Comment: Thank you @Clay! Your comment led me to a solution. Write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says that **The lifetime of the current game's connection to the room is bound to this GoogleApiClient's lifecycle.** So maybe you have to restart your `GoogleApiClient`